# NCMBのオブジェクトを削除したい。

Tags: monaca

Monacaとnifty cloudで開発を行っております。
データストアに保存したオブジェクトをdestroyで削除したいのですが、その場合にobjectIdを取得してきて削除すればよいのでしょうか？
sample.get("objectId");としてもobjectIdがundefinedで返って来てしまいます。
また、そうでないのなら具体的な方法などをご教授お願い致します。

```
var Notice = NCMB.Object.extend("notice");
var noticeQuery = new NCMB.Query("notice");

var notice = new Notice();
var array = new Array();

noticeQuery.find({
            //成功時
    success: function(objects) {
        for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            array[i] = objects[i].get("objectId");
            notice.set("objectId", array[0]);
            notice.destroy();
            notice.save();
        }
    },

    //失敗時
    error: function(error) {
        //エラー表示
        alert('Failed to get object, with error code: ' + error.description);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/datastore/basic_usage_javascript.html#オブジェクトの削除](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/datastore/basic_usage_javascript.html#%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E5%89%8A%E9%99%A4)

1.2系はドキュメントもなくなってしまったので定かではありませんが…。

`objects[i].destroy({

  success: function() {

    // 削除完了

  },

  error: function() {

    // 削除失敗

  }

});`

ではうまくいかないでしょうか？